# Pass parameter to selector function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, parameters, selector

I would like to pass a *parameter* to a function called as a *selector* from a *timer*.  Specifically the reference to a `cell` so i can update something in the *UI*.

So what I want to something like this:

```
timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(downloadTimer(cell: cell), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Function

```
func downloadTimer(cell: InnerCollectionCell) {
    cell.progressBar.setProgress(downloadProgress, animated: true)
}
```

Though I might be a bit niece in assuming this can be done?

------ EDIT ------

As per the below examples, but not getting expected results as usual from a cell

```
let innerCell: InnerCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierInner, for: indexPath) as! InnerCollectionCell

timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(downloadTimer(_:)), userInfo: innerCell, repeats: true)


func downloadTimer(_ timer: Timer) {

    let cell = timer.userInfo

    cell. // no options as expected of a cell

}
```

[image]

I expected more options like this if the data was sent correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set your timer with the userinfo

```
timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(downloadTimer(cell: cell), userInfo: data, repeats: true)
```

and get userinfo as follow

```
func downloadTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
   let data = timer.userInfo
}
```

------ EDIT ------

As per the below examples, but not getting expected results as usual from a cell

```
let innerCell: InnerCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierInner, for: indexPath) as! InnerCollectionCell

timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(downloadTimer(_:)), userInfo: innerCell, repeats: true)


func downloadTimer(_ timer: Timer) {

    let cell = timer.userInfo as! InnerCollectionCell

    cell. // no options as expected of a cell

}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry i attached this in the wrong box and it won't let me remove it

Comment: casting cell as a InnerCollectionCell

Comment: let cell = timer.userInfo as InnerCollectionCell

Answer (score 9):

You pass in the data you want as the userInfo argument when creating the Timer:

```
timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(downloadTimer(_:), userInfo: myData, repeats: true)
```

and make the callback look like:

```
func downloadTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    // access timer.userInfo here
}
```